# Go - how to append marshalled json object to a file

Tags: arrays, json, go, marshalling

Is there a way to append marshalled json object into json array inside a file, without loading that file?

Here is what I mean:

```
Contents of "file.json":

// json array
[
    // json objects
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
    // APPEND NEW marshalled json object here
]
```

If that's not possible or not efficient, then how viable is holding 20MB worth of structs in a slice for a long period of time?

Comment: Not sure if there's an elegant solution to this, other than a hack where you remove the last array square brace, append the json object and then add the brace again. However, if you're holding 20MB worth of data in a single file then maybe you should consider going for a db solution, such as mongodb.

Comment: If you do go for a hacky solution, make sure there is only ever one thread writing to the file.

Comment: I think this is a good question for whoever might come across the same issue. The answers are great, as well. Don't know who voted -1, but I think it should be used as a last resort more wisely.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to operate on the raw byte stream, you can remove the closing tags, append the new json objects in and rewrite the closing tags again.